# How do i clear the contents of a "select" using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

New to jquery! How do i clear the contents of a html "select" using jquery? Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) all options:

```
$("#mySelect > option").remove();
```